# IKImageBrowserView in iOS?

Tags: ios, image

I am trying to develop an application that needs to display pictures in a gallery view. One of the seemingly most straightforward ways to do this is use the IKImageBrowserView. But I cant find any info pertaining to the iPhone. Would anyone out there have a better suggestion for displaying a gallery of photos on iOS? I also want to have the ability to tag the photos, if you guys have any suggestions for that it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a collection of data in a grid format (i.e. a gallery of photos) you should look at UICollectionView.